# What is the effect on SEO with a Meteor application?

Tags: html, seo, meteor

Looking at the rendered HTML source code for the todos list example, there is zero code in the body tag. How does this affect SEO?

Answer (score 22):

**EDIT**: Meteor now supports serving static HTML to spiders.

From: http://docs.meteor.com/#spiderable

Can Meteor serve static HTML? Can Meteor sites be indexed by Google?

Yes. Add the "spiderable" smart package to include support for emitting static HTML to search engines, complete with valid links. The spiderable package implements Google's AJAX Crawling Specification. See the spiderable documentation for details.

This version of spiderable is specifically for search engines. A future version of Meteor will also send HTML to web browsers on inital page load. The Meteor templating system was designed specifically to support this use case.

**Old and now wrong answer:**

From: http://meteor.com/faq/can-meteor-serve-static-html

Can Meteor serve static HTML? Does Meteor work with JavaScript disabled on the client? Can Meteor sites be indexed by Google?

Meteor has been carefully designed to support this important use case, but it's not in the current Meteor builds. It will be part of our upcoming Routing release, which will make it easy to build Meteor sites that are aware of the current URL.

Briefly, the way server-side rendering works is that the Meteor app is started on the server and allowed to render the page. Then the session state is serialized (using the same migration technology behind Hot Code Push) and the app is frozen and pushed down to the browser, where it can optionally be restarted if the browser supports JavaScript. Since Meteor templating is based on HTML strings, not DOM manipulation, it's not necessary to run a DOM emulation package on the server.

Comment: Any chance to update the answer with the current quote from http://meteor.com/faq/can-meteor-serve-static-html ?

[[Yes. Add the "spiderable" smart package to include support for emitting static HTML to search engines, complete with valid links. The spiderable package implements Google's AJAX Crawling Specification. See the spiderable documentation for details.

This version of spiderable is specifically for search engines. A future version of Meteor will also send HTML to web browsers on inital page load. The Meteor templating system was designed specifically to support this use case.]]

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: I wrote a blog post on this topic and I also created a little SEO helper package -> http://manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo

Comment: You said: *A future version of Meteor will also send HTML to web browsers on inital page load.*. Could you add a reference for this? I haven't seen any official information on this,

Answer (score 0):

since spiders have no js execution that would mean they would only get any info in the head about the page which wouldn't really be good, however it looks like looking at their site that you can still have static content as well as streaming in other content which would be fine for SEO if your static content was talking about key phrases, had links to other site etc that are relevant to your desired keywords

Comment: On top of that Meteor advantages probably don't apply for usecases where SEO is important but more for real-time application where data change often. That doesn't mean that some parts can't be served with static content but its probably not what Meteor is best for.

Comment: Google does run JavaScript on your site, I've tested this.

Comment: Google's documentation: [Making AJAX applications crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) (as nowadays supported by the  spiderable package).